# Cannot find source map Load canceled due to load timeout angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

Hi am encountering an issue in devtool all browsers.I cant find the sourcemap files
On my local environment i can see the files but on testing environment the files are partially generated showing only like 2 files.

I have the following error on dev tool Load canceled due to load timeout

```
pathofwebsite/main.4445e8d17fbdfbf85760.js      Load canceled due to load timeout
```

In the developer tool javascript sourcemap is enabled and there is no extension installed. I have even clear cache several time did not work. Also crossed if anti virus was blocking it but seem not to be the reason. Is related to connection issue ?Thank you for your feedback

Comment: This happens when the server gets disconnected.  Try restarting your localhost server and rebooting your app.  Hope that helps.